# Neo4j GraphQL graphql.idl no interface generated

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I am testing the Neo4j GraphQL plugin.
I have an IDL schema, which I pass on to Neo4j:

```
CALL graphql.idl(
'type Address {
  id: ID!
  display_name: String
  adress_spec: AddrSpec!
  adress_from: Originator! @relation(name: "From")
  adress_sender: Originator @relation(name: "Sender")
  adress_reply_to: Originator @relation(name: "ReplyTo")
  destination_to: [Destination] @relation(name: "To")
  destination_cc: [Destination] @relation(name: "Cc")
  destination_bcc: [Destination] @relation(name: "Bcc")
}

type Originator {
  id: ID!
  origin_date: Datetime!
  originator_role: originator_role!
  message: [Message!] @relation(name: "Originator")
  address_from: Address! @relation(name: "From")
  address_sender: Address @relation(name: "Sender")
  address_reply_to: Address @relation(name: "ReplyTo")
}

type Destination {
  id: ID!
  destination_role: destination_role!
  received_date: Datetime!
  message: Message! @relation(name: "Destination")
  address_to: [Address]! @relation(name: "To")
  address_cc: [Address] @relation(name: "Cc")
  address_bcc: [Address] @relation(name: "Bcc")
}

type Message {
  id: ID!
  subject: String
  comments: String
  originator: Originator! @relation(name: "Originator")
  destinations: [Destination]! @relation(name: "HasDestination")
  referencing: [Message] @relation(name: "Referencing")
  in_reply_to: [Message] @relation(name: "InReplyTo")
  keywords: [Keyword] @relation(name: "Tags")
}

type Keyword {
  id: ID!
  keyword: String!
  messages: [Message] @relation(name: "Tags")
}
');
```

And I do get an interface description:

```
"{Address=MetaData{type='Address', properties={id=PropertyInfo(fieldName=id, type=ID!, id=true, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null), display_name=PropertyInfo(fieldName=display_name, type=String, id=false, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null)}, labels=[], relationships={adress_spec=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=adress_spec, type=adress_spec, label=AddrSpec, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), adress_from=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=adress_from, type=From, label=Originator, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), adress_sender=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=adress_sender, type=Sender, label=Originator, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), adress_reply_to=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=adress_reply_to, type=ReplyTo, label=Originator, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), destination_to=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=destination_to, type=To, label=Destination, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), destination_cc=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=destination_cc, type=Cc, label=Destination, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), destination_bcc=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=destination_bcc, type=Bcc, label=Destination, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0)}, isInterface=false}, Originator=MetaData{type='Originator', properties={id=PropertyInfo(fieldName=id, type=ID!, id=true, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null)}, labels=[], relationships={origin_date=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=origin_date, type=origin_date, label=Datetime, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), originator_role=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=originator_role, type=originator_role, label=originator_role, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), message=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=message, type=Originator, label=Message, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), address_from=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=address_from, type=From, label=Address, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), address_sender=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=address_sender, type=Sender, label=Address, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), address_reply_to=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=address_reply_to, type=ReplyTo, label=Address, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0)}, isInterface=false}, Destination=MetaData{type='Destination', properties={id=PropertyInfo(fieldName=id, type=ID!, id=true, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null)}, labels=[], relationships={destination_role=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=destination_role, type=destination_role, label=destination_role, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), received_date=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=received_date, type=received_date, label=Datetime, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), message=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=message, type=Destination, label=Message, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), address_to=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=address_to, type=To, label=Address, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), address_cc=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=address_cc, type=Cc, label=Address, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), address_bcc=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=address_bcc, type=Bcc, label=Address, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0)}, isInterface=false}, Message=MetaData{type='Message', properties={id=PropertyInfo(fieldName=id, type=ID!, id=true, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null), subject=PropertyInfo(fieldName=subject, type=String, id=false, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null), comments=PropertyInfo(fieldName=comments, type=String, id=false, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null)}, labels=[], relationships={originator=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=originator, type=Originator, label=Originator, out=true, multi=false, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), destinations=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=destinations, type=HasDestination, label=Destination, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=1), referencing=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=referencing, type=Referencing, label=Message, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), in_reply_to=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=in_reply_to, type=InReplyTo, label=Message, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0), keywords=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=keywords, type=Tags, label=Keyword, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0)}, isInterface=false}, Keyword=MetaData{type='Keyword', properties={id=PropertyInfo(fieldName=id, type=ID!, id=true, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null), keyword=PropertyInfo(fieldName=keyword, type=String!, id=true, indexed=false, cypher=null, defaultValue=null, unique=false, enum=false, parameters=null, description=null)}, labels=[], relationships={messages=RelationshipInfo(fieldName=messages, type=Tags, label=Message, out=true, multi=true, cypher=null, parameters=null, description=null, nonNull=0)}, isInterface=false}}"
```

However, in GraphiQL there is no schema description and in Neo4j I get an error when asking:

```
call graphql.schema()
```

Result:

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `graphql.schema`: Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Any suggestions?

/Thomas

Here is an extract from the log:

> 2018-04-24 18:58:01.395+0000 WARN  /graphql/
>   kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLSchemaBuilder.newReferenceField(GraphQLSchemaBuilder.kt:262)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLSchemaBuilder.addRelationships(GraphQLSchemaBuilder.kt:228)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLSchemaBuilder.toGraphQLObjectType(GraphQLSchemaBuilder.kt:180)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLSchemaBuilder.graphQlTypes(GraphQLSchemaBuilder.kt:662)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLSchemaBuilder.buildSchema(GraphQLSchemaBuilder.kt:387)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLSchemaBuilder$Companion.buildSchema(GraphQLSchemaBuilder.kt:338)
>     at org.neo4j.graphql.GraphSchema.getGraphQL(GraphSchema.kt:19)  at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLResource.executeQuery(GraphQLResource.kt:80)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.graphql.GraphQLResource.executeOperation(GraphQLResource.kt:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationEnabledFilter.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2018-04-24 19:11:54.733+0000
>   INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request 2018-04-24
>   19:11:54.784+0000 INFO  Stopping... 2018-04-24 19:11:54.871+0000 INFO 
>   Stopped.

Comment: What type are `destination_role`,`AddrSpec` and `Datetime`? can you try without those?

Comment: You also have to specify the direction if it is not the default `direcition="OUT"` but `direction="IN"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

I changed

- DateTime to String
- the *_ role to String
- AddressSpec to String
- Added directions

then

```
CALL graphql.idl(
'type Address {
  id: ID!
  display_name: String
  adress_spec: String!
  adress_from: Originator! @relation(name: "From")
  adress_sender: Originator @relation(name: "Sender")
  adress_reply_to: Originator @relation(name: "ReplyTo")
  destination_to: [Destination] @relation(name: "To")
  destination_cc: [Destination] @relation(name: "Cc")
  destination_bcc: [Destination] @relation(name: "Bcc")
}

type Originator {
  id: ID!
  origin_date: String!
  originator_role: String!
  message: [Message!] @relation(name: "Originator", direction:"IN")
  address_from: Address! @relation(name: "From", direction:"IN")
  address_sender: Address @relation(name: "Sender", direction:"IN")
  address_reply_to: Address @relation(name: "ReplyTo", direction:"IN")
}

type Destination {
  id: ID!
  destination_role: String!
  received_date: String!
  message: Message! @relation(name: "Destination", direction:"IN")
  address_to: [Address]! @relation(name: "To", direction:"IN")
  address_cc: [Address] @relation(name: "Cc", direction:"IN")
  address_bcc: [Address] @relation(name: "Bcc", direction:"IN")
}

type Message {
  id: ID!
  subject: String
  comments: String
  originator: Originator! @relation(name: "Originator")
  destinations: [Destination]! @relation(name: "HasDestination")
  referencing: [Message] @relation(name: "Referencing")
  in_reply_to: [Message] @relation(name: "InReplyTo")
  keywords: [Keyword] @relation(name: "Tags")
}

type Keyword {
  id: ID!
  keyword: String!
  messages: [Message] @relation(name: "Tags", direction:"IN")
}
');
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this: call graphql.idl('type Movie {
  id: ID
  title: String
  tagline: String
  released: Int
  actors: [Person] @relation(name: "ACTED_IN", direction: "IN")
  recommended: [Movie] @cypher(statement:"MATCH (this)-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]-(rec:Movie) RETURN rec LIMIT 10")
}
type Person {
  id: ID
  name: String
  born: Int
  movies: [Movie] @relation(name: "ACTED_IN", direction: "OUT")
}') and it works like a charm. Any idea what part of my original source is problematic?

Comment: And your version of my example works fine for me, too. Incl. GraphoQL. Thanks for the assistance Michael.

Comment: see my comments at the beginning

Comment: Yes, I noticed them (now) and I am happy with them. It makes sense to use the Neo4j data types, obviously ;-)